# google cloud function 75s delay

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have some code which using asyncio/aiohttp calls out to a google cloud function.

```
invoking functions 7098
fetched file_paths 2.9615896589999995 # irrelavant
finished call 0.5879122549999991
finished call 75.623789222
```

If I run 40 such calls I also get the 75 late maybe after half of them or someting.
The execution of the function are always about .3 seconds.

I trie to increase auto scale minimum to 20 but it does not go away.
I can rerun it many times and it always had some calls fast then a very very long delay which makes no sense.

Does anybody have an idea where this can some from. It cannot be cold boot or the first call would also be so slow, or warm functions should return faster.

UPDATE:

```py
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async def future(single_input: Dict[str, Any]) -> dict:
        start_f = perf_counter()
        async with session.request(**map_inputs_to_request_params_fn(single_input)) as response:
            result = await response.json(encoding="UTF-8", content_type=None)
            if timeit:
                stop_f = perf_counter()
                print(f"finished call {stop_f - start_f}")
            return result
    tasks = [future(d) for d in inputs]
    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return responses
```

All of the code runs inside and async function but after the await gather there is no await anymore. Just sync code until the `result = new_loop.run_until_complete(async_exec())`

Comment: Can you share the code that you have to create that case? Do you continue the work async after answering the request in the Cloud Functions?

Comment: I update the code if if I have 90 calls. 45 finsih in 4 seconds, then next 45 in 75 seconds. It is like I send 90 calls at once, google makes two queues and then handle the second queue 70+ seconds later. Autoscaling is set from 2-30 and according to metrics it only had 7 instances peak.
If I send 2 calls its the same one in 3 seconds 1 in 75.

Comment: I'm not good enough in Python to help you (maybe other will). But the behavior that you describe is typically the case where you continue to work in background after the return. You have to know that the CPU of the cloud function is throttle (less than 5% of CPU is allowed outside any request processing) and that's why the request take so much time to be completed.

Comment: Can you please try increasing the memory and CPU of the machine and try the running the cloud function again?

Answer (score -1):

Posting the answer based on my comment and also based on the previous one from other community members.

It seems like the issue is with the system reaching maximum CPU and memory limits. The memory size and CPU are connected. If you increase memory. CPU limit also increases. You can increase the memory either by going to console -> cloud functions -> click on the cloud function for which  you want to increase the memory -> click edit -> and in the Runtime, build, connections and security settings section you have runtime section where you can increase the memory, or you can also use CLI to increase the memory.
You can use the following command

```
gcloud functions deploy function_name ... --memory 512MB
```

You can check the following [CLI documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy).